# Card Reader Output into Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, mobile

I am trying to design a Visualforce point of sale terminal, which can be accessed on an iPad or other tablet. It would be very nice if I could connect a card reader such that the card info would be entered directly into the Visualforce page so that it could then be processed (via Stripe, Paypal, or other API's). Does anyone know of a good reader/library that could accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have some major challenges designing something like that in visualforce because of how particular mobile phones are about accessing microphone jacks or usb ports.  Your best bet is going to need to be some sort of Hybrid mobile application where your native application can intercept information from the mobile phone and feed it to the webpage.

You won't be able to directly access a card reader from a webpage (visualforce or not).  If you were developing a desktop application, there may be the opportunity to use a browser plugin or extension to accomplish the connection.

Comment: Bradley is correct. This is the perfect use case for Hybrid Mobile Applications. Saleforce.com has released an SDK for this also. Take a look here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, you may want to look in the App Exchange. There's something called [Payment Center](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000030P1xEAE) that integrates with PayPal which already exists that you may want to check out. Its mobile compatible.

I know you can interface with card readers without too much difficulty. One of our Dallas SFDUG members connected a card reader for a charity we worked with during Give Camp in Oct 2013 so their volunteers could log-in and log-out of their projects to more easily track their time, but I've no idea what he did to create the controller interface within SF to read the digital signal that came from it. He also didn't need to deal with the security issues that you obviously will need to for a secure transaction.