# Hardware and service to setup salesforce as a retail point of sale card reader and payment processing

Tags: integration

I have seen this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/62996/card-reader-output-into-salesforce) which is similar, however my question relates to regular desktop ui not mobile.

Does anyone know of a card reader or service(credit card / chip n pin) that can take payments and be connected to salesforce to store transactions. Salesforce is to be used as the epos in a retail environment.

*note I am aware of web based payment processing services, here we need retail point-of-sale, chip n pin approach.

I don't need a full app solution, happy to undertake any dev integration as needed, just need a starter in the right direction.

Comment: Regardless of what you do, you'll still need payment processing through some kind of interbank handling service that will either be internet or modem based, plus your connection to SF. The solution is really no different than the one you've referenced in your post. There are MANY apps on the app exchange that already exist. Non profits and web merchants use them all the time. They can also be used for retail in the same manner. I think PayPal has an API you may want to look at.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [SuiteRetail](http://www.suiteretail.com). The only proven POS for Salesforce. Seamless offline/online, EMV chip and used by many known brands.